# UIButton Animation not working

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, animatewithduration

I am new at xcode and I am learning something new each day, I have gotten stuck. I want to create a custom button on a second Storyboard (MapTwoViewController), lets say it is a custom button that looks like a cloud and it goes from left to right.

I have created the custom button in the storyboard and I have created the IBOutlet in the GWSMapTwoViewController.h so it looks like this and is linked to the button:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GWSMapTwoViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *cloudAnimate;

@end
```

So in my GWSMapTwoViewController.m in my view did load I have the following:

```
#import "GWSMapTwoViewController.h"

@interface GWSMapTwoViewController ()

@end

@implementation GWSMapTwoViewController
@synthesize cloudAnimate;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Move UIView

    cloudAnimate.center = CGPointMake(200.0, 100.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{ cloudAnimate.center = CGPointMake(100.0, 200.0);}];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

It just doesn't want to animate, it just goes straight to the end point, if I remove the animation code then the cloud appears at 200, 100 but if I put the animate code in it just moves to 100, 200 or whatever coordinates i put in. It just doesn't animate so its either in the starting point or the end point.

Can anyone tell when what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. What version of xCode / iOS are you using and targeting ?

Comment: 5.0.2 what Dimentar said below worked!

Comment: Ok good - must be a difference between simulator and device - the above code works on the simulator for some reason :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your animation code in

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

because viewDidLoad is called before the view is visible.

Don't forget to call super

Comment: His code works for me exactly as it is - I think there is something else he is doing that's causing the problem.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad is fore Initialization , not for animation

Comment: OK it would be good if I could get to the bottom of why it is working for others and not for me but what Dimentar said worked. Hmmm